# In R looking for a value in the row below

Tags: r

I'm trying to look for a value in a row below the one being evaluated. So for example, if I have df X and I want to create another variable called samp3 that returns a value of 1 each time B occurs in samp2 but I want it to return one row above B.

```
x <- data.frame(
  samp1=c(5,6,7,5,4,5,10,5,6,7), 
  samp2=c("A","A","B","C","B","A","A","A","A","A")
)

x$samp3 <- ifelse(x$samp2 =="B", 1, NA)
```

This will work if it's on the same row, but I'm not sure how to change this to return the value of 1 on the row above.

Ideally I'd get a df like the one below.

```
x <- data.frame(
  samp1=c(5,6,7,5,4,5,10,5,6,7), 
  samp2=c("A","A","B","C","B","A","A","A","A","A"),
  samp3=c(NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One ways could be using `dplyr::lead`

```r
x <- data.frame(
    samp1=c(5,6,7,5,4,5,10,5,6,7), 
    samp2=c("A","A","B","C","B","A","A","A","A","A"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
x$samp3  <- ifelse(dplyr::lead(x$samp2,1,default = "NA") == "B",1,0)
```

```r
> x
   samp1 samp2 samp3
1      5     A     0
2      6     A     1
3      7     B     0
4      5     C     1
5      4     B     0
6      5     A     0
7     10     A     0
8      5     A     0
9      6     A     0
10     7     A     0
```

Comment: Modified my answer using `lead`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I like this way, it very intuitive for me!

Answer (score 1):

here is a data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)

x[, samp3 := ifelse(shift(samp2, -1) == "B", 1, NA)]
```

Comment: I keep getting an error that says shift can't accept a negative "Error in shift(Event, -1) : n must be non-negative integer values (>= 0)"

Comment: I have `data.table` 1.12.4. Which version do you have?

Comment: It could be you're using another package that masks `shift`. In the code I provided, replace `shift` by `data.table::shift`. It should work

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(x, samp3 = ifelse(c(as.character(samp2)[-1], NA) == "B", 1, NA))
#   samp1 samp2 samp3
#1      5     A    NA
#2      6     A     1
#3      7     B    NA
#4      5     C     1
#5      4     B    NA
#6      5     A    NA
#7     10     A    NA
#8      5     A    NA
#9      6     A    NA
#10     7     A    NA
```

Comment: Hi asasdasd - Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please will you add some more detail to your answer? It would help if you explain *how* this works and how it answers the question?